# React Moment Offset Issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, momentjs, utc

I am using react moment library to format my time however I keep getting the time offset added to it. There is nothing in the docs to explain how to give you the local date so I was wondering if anyone can help.

So what I am trying is:

`<Moment format="HH:mm" utc tz="Europe/London" date="2020-04-08T21:00:00.000Z" local>  </Moment>`

I have tried different combinations between them all but nothing seems to be working. 
The utc is not mentioned in docs but I have seen other stack overflow posts where its suggested.

Please help

Comment: To add I am getting time 22:00 instead of 21:00

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to achieve. You get a time offset because London is +1.

Comment: Sorry I want to not have an offset added to it but nothing seems to work

Comment: Seems to me `...utc tz="Europe/London"  date="2020-04-08T21:00:00.000Z" local` specifies both UTC and local. Shouldn't you remove one or the other?

Comment: Ive tried a combination of them with and without local but nothing did the trick

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use the moment library instead of react moment or any of the other libraries.

```
npm install moment --save
npm install moment-timezone
```

```
const timezone="America/Los_Angeles";
const date="2020-04-08T21:00:00.000Z";
moment().tz(timezone).format(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<Moment format="HH:mm" date="2020-04-08T21:00:00.000Z" utc/>
```

There's no documentation on the [`utc` prop](https://github.com/headzoo/react-moment/search?q=utc&unscoped_q=utc) but it does what you expect:

```
<time datetime="1586379600000">21:00</time>
```